# Spring cloud stream with bind kafka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I am new to spring cloud and  I'm searching for any simple complete example for spring cloud stream using kafka broker.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the samples repo [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples) and use `Kafka` binder in the sample application if it has a binder other than `Kafka`.